# Gosu annotation for validating DOB

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I'm working in gosu(guidewire) and having an annotation for the Date Of Birth(DOB).The expression under that annotation is supposed to return an error if the year of the DOB is less than 1897 or if it is greater than 2001.

I'm new to gosu so can someone please help me with this?

Comment: have any code example to share of what you have done so far? also what version of Guidewire and product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB annotation for DOB Validation. 
You have to create custom annotation for achieving the same.

Create New Gosu Class -> Change the kind as **Annotation**

Answer (score 1):

There is a DateRange annotation which sounds like it would meet your requirements.  It has been around for a while although this question might have predated the implementation.  You would not want a static test as your requirements change annually.  It looks like 16 years was the minimum age and 120 is the maximum.

@JsonProperty

@DateRange(Expr.const(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-(120 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *365))), Expr.const(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-(16 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365))))

protected var _dateOfBirth: LocalDateDTO as DateOfBirth